# About command line arguments of main function

Tags: c++, c, arguments, program-entry-point

It will look like `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`. My questions are:

1 How many array items can I add in `argv[]`?

2 What is MAX size of every `char *`?

Comment: I think it's implementation-dependent, you cannot rely on any specific bound.

Comment: If you need to pass so many parameters that you need to think about these upper bounds, your might be doing something wrong. You probably need some form of IPC.

Comment: But _why_ do you need this information? If you need, perhaps you are doing something wrong.

Comment: 1 I use linux
2 I will pass a lot info to it by PHP script using exec().
3 I think use file to exchange the data will cost more time than using arguments of main function.
thanks

Comment: @javas: a file is not the only form of IPC, for example you could use `popen` and write a lot of data through the pipe. But on linux, command lines are allowed to be very long anyway, to support things like `ls *log`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2180000
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/limits.h.html

> ARG_MAX is maximum length of argument to the exec functions including environment data.

That is, there is no individual limit on the number of arguments or argument's length. Only the limit on total size required to store all the arguments and environment variables.

[`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) figures out maximum command line length using `sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX);` which yields the same value as reported by `getconf ARG_MAX`.

On Linux command line arguments and environment variables are put into new process' stack. So, the process/thread maximum stack size is the ultimate upper bound. Linux-specific limits are [hardcoded in the kernel](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/include/linux/binfmts.h#L14):

```
#define MAX_ARG_STRLEN (PAGE_SIZE * 32)
#define MAX_ARG_STRINGS 0x7FFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 3):

Both of those are bounded only by how much memory you have (or how much memory your OS gives your program).

EDIT: Actually, the number of arguments is also bounded by the size of `int`.

Comment: Or how much memory your OS gives for the cmd line (which is quite limited in most OSs out there, and sometimes very hardcoded)

Comment: I think this answer is answering "what is the max size of any char* ever", whereas the questioner, probably due to a misunderstanding, is asking what the maximum size of the `char*`s in argv[] are.

Comment: Windows gives you very little memory (sometimes it chokes on just a few kB of command line args), while all Unix platforms are so generous that if you need more, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what's going on here.  You don't, in your code, add anything to argv[], and you don't worry about their maximum sizes.  When somebody runs your compiled program, as

```
./javas_program argument1 argument2 argument3
```

then your main function will be called.  `argc` will be 4, `argv[0]` will be `./javas_program`, `argv[1]` will be `argument1`, `argv[2]` will be `argument2`, etc.

In your program, you should assume that the contents of `argv[]` can be any size.  If you want to limit them to a specific size, you should check that they're not larger than that.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the mechanism you are using to start your program. If it is through a shell (`bash` or whatever) you'd have to look up if it imposes restrictions.

If you start your program through `execv` or something similar, they should only be subject to the same restrictions as any array and string, and, as somebody noted, because `argc` is `int` for historical reasons, to the limited size of `int` not of `size_t`.