# What is the size of argument list in C/C++ main function and indetermined behavior

Tags: c++, c, security

I would like to know what is the maximum size of the list of arguments in C/C++ main function? Does it depend on the OS? And what happens if I pass the very large number of arguments to the main function, the main function behavior will be indetermined?

Thanks,

Comment: I mean how many we can pass and is it a security issue if I pass the number of arguments bigger than the maximun size?

Comment: check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419464/c-argv-what-is-the-maximum-size-of-data) for a theoretical discussion of argument sizes. what context requires this knowledge ?

Comment: @channgo2203 I think Linux restricts the size of the argument vector to 128 kB. Generally, if you try to start a program with more arguments, the call to `exec` fails.

Comment: thanks FUZxxl, however, in the main(int argc, char* argv) if I pass to argc the very large number and the list of strings to argv such that they are smaller than 128KB, what happens, maybe exec fails, I will check it.

Comment: @channgo2203 Why should anything strange happen in such a case? The array of pointers `argv` counts towards the 128 kB; you won't get any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it depends on OS, but the limitation is about number of characters that can be passed to a process rather than the number of arguments. See this: [Maximum Length of Command Line String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205027/maximum-length-of-command-line-string)

Comment: thanks rubix_addict, is there secuirty issue if the number of characters is large and the strings are ill-formed?