# Passing large amounts of data to a CLI command

Tags: command-line-interface

Let's say I had 10MB string to pass to a CLI command.

Could I directly pass it in the CLI? eg. `my_cmd "my_string"`
Or maybe `my_cmd << file_with_data`?

Or would I have to write it to disk first and then the command internally read the file?

Could I pass the command a memory location of the string?

What other options exist?

====

EDIT:
To be clear my question is about passing a **huge** string through a CLI. Are there size limits? Other issues?

EDIT 2:
I would be passing this data from a program to a child process, written in different languages.

Comment: What is your question? Of course it's possible to feed a cli command with a string? PLease show us an example of the real issue.

Comment: Made an edit. @0stone0

Comment: I've tried to do something similar before and I remember running into issues.  I think it depends on either the OS or the shell, but there is generally a buffer with a limit somewhere.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit).  I would definitely just pass the data through a file.

Comment: On what system are you? AFAIK Posix says at least 4096.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419464/c-argv-what-is-the-maximum-size-of-data and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498892/about-command-line-arguments-of-main-function

Comment: From where do you get the data? If they are in a file, why not read the file. If you give them from one program to a child, you could try using shared memory, pipes or sockets.

Comment: From a program to a child.

Comment: stdin and stdout would be the simplest, a socket would be more advanced but has some advantages. Shared memory is a bit harder when you use different languages.

Answer (score 1):

10MB shouldn't be an issue, you could verify this like so;

Use the following command to generate [10MB random data](https://superuser.com/questions/692175/how-to-create-a-random-txthuman-readable-text-like-ascii-file-in-linux):
`base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 10000000`, now use [`<<<`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash) to feed it to your command;

```
wc -l <<< $(base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 10000000) # 0.42s
```

```
grep -i 'z' <<< $(base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 10000000) # 0.61s
```

<sub>I'm using the unix [time](https://ss64.com/bash/time.html) to check the duration</sub>

---

If you wish to (temporary) write the data to a file, use:
`base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 10000000 > file_10_mb.txt`

```
wc -l < file_10_mb.txt # 0.01s
```

```
grep 'z' < file_10_mb.txt | wc -l # 0.07
```

---

If your `my_cmd` doesn't require a lot of resources, 10MB should work just fine

Comment: Can I do the same without first creating a file? I would like to skip the step of writing to disk for performance reasons.

Comment: I think you missunderstood the question. The question was if an argument of the size of 10 MB can be passed. Basically `command "$(cat <10Mb file>)"` without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get an answer to the limit see the related question and answers here: [About command line arguments of main function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498892/about-command-line-arguments-of-main-function)
It seems like 10 MB is a bit large and much larger than the minimum for Posix which is 4096. On my AMD64 Linux the limit is about 2 MiB.

For better options: There are files, pipes (including stdin and stdout), sockets or shared memory.